# Не изменяет данные при выполнения комманды

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Всем привет. Почему данные не изменяются при выполнение команды? Как был пустой текстовый файл так и остался. Я хочу что-бы id пользователя дискорда написавшего комманду записался в текстовый файл.

```
@bot.command()
async def edit(ctx):
    author_id = str(message.author.id)
    with open("tempid.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(author_id))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: может author_id пустая строка?

Comment: вот этого знать не могу, но если вроде комманда с if message content == то всё работает

Comment: Может не `message.author.id`, а `ctx.author.id`. Message то от куда у вас взялся?

Comment: Спасибо! Не заметил свою ошибку. Всё заработало!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message -> ctx

```
@bot.command()
async def edit(ctx):
    author_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    with open("tempid.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(author_id))
```